# How to use two... function? in jQuery to display DIV on by two DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

On start I say, that my english is very bad, so I long wondered, whether here write, and whether You will understand Me.

I have the following jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#div1').hover(function() {
        $('#div1').css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {
        $('#div2').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

This script has to do this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW7Lp.png

And it does :)
But, when I take the cursor from the string "Strona główna", the second DIV disappears :(

How I can create... something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#div1' + '#div2').hover(function() {
        $('#div1').css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {
        $('#div2').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

I do not know much about jQuery :(

Please help me,
I hope, I wrote it understandable.

At a glance...
Div1 and Div2 must display Div2 when cursor is on area Div1 and Div2 :P

I tried to create a simple sliding menu, but I must use Div, because the entire site is written in Divs, and this menu (on picture) already is in other Div...

This panel with this menu is on my Tumblr, so you can see it on : idolwszutrab7.tumblr.com if it helps, but I have not updated the page with this script.

**Update:**

I copy all to:

http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/Wq3YH/

I tested it, and it work in this site :)

Comment: Please add your `html` to the question.

Comment: Place it at the bottom of your question. Or recreate your problem on jsfiddle.net

Comment: +1 for the jsfiddle recommendation.

Comment: +1? What +1? What this is?

Comment: +1 is shorthand for "I agree"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got idea, to create two scripts :P

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#div1').hover(function() {
            $('#div2').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('#div2').hover(function() {
            $('#div2').css('display', 'block');
        }, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('#div2').css('display', 'none');
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's work!

After, I added animations and effects,
so now it looks nice, and as yet works.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for what you want

as you want to show div2 on hover of div1 and div2

```
$('#div1 , #div2').hover(function() {
    $('#div2').css('display', 'block');
}, function() {
    $('#div2').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Just make sure there is no space between those two div other wise on hover out of first div 2nd div will close before reaching there.

Other option is to wrap those two div with other div say div3 and give hover on div3

like

```
<div id='div3'>
 <div id='div1'>

</div><div id='div2'>

</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#div3').hover(function() {
    $('#div2').css('display', 'block');
}, function() {
    $('#div2').css('display', 'none');
});
```

In second way there is pure css way too.
**CSS**

```
#div3 #div2{
display:none;
}
#div3:hover #div2{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: But in "div3" are other divs and other links, and I want that only one link show div2, when cursor is on div1 and div2 :)

Comment: before working with this script I tried with css : #div3:hover #div2 but not work :/